# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: issue coming while running maven build

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting the below issue while trying to run the maven build . Project runs fine in java application but while running maven build getting the below issue . How can i resolve this

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project spring-boot-library-design: Fatal error
> compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x138aa3cc)
> cannot access class
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module
> jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x138aa3cc -> [Help
> 1]